# Styling an element using inline javascript on onclick

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a link. I have an external stylesheet and in the HTML I am pointing to the correct location of the sheet, so that is not the problem. I would like to change the `text-decoration` when the `onclick` event is triggered. I have:

```
<a class="dopelink"onclick="document.getElementsByTagName("link").style.textDecoration="underline" " href="mylink.htm" >MY Link</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code, fiddle, anything?

Comment: @davidfromMLogicinc You have to post your code.

Comment: You have problem with quotes. Use single quotes inside double ones.

Comment: Are `a` tags underlined by default? clicking on the `a` will force a page change, so any changes to css would be reset anyhow. maybe add `return false;` to the `onclick` function.

Comment: figured it out.  was simple.  i chose to use addEventListner.  thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="dopelink" style="text-decoration:none" onmousedown="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" href="mylink.htm">My link</a>
```

Your javascript must use single-quotes because your HTML uses double-quotes.

Set the `text-decoration` to `none` since it is underlined by default. This will change when the element is clicked.

Use `this` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`. Since it's inline javascript, it can reference itself.

Use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`.

Comment: thanks for illustrating the proper sytanx.  still need help with making the thing work though.

Comment: i tried it several types of ways earlier including the way you suggested and it didn't work.  I also tried again after your suggestion.  still 0 action.

Comment: tired using a instead of link too.  still nope.  even a:link.  this is an external sheet, not inline css.

Comment: @davidfromMLogicinc I tested it in my browser, and, it _is_ working, the problem is that it underlines it on mouse _up_. If you want it to underline it on mouse _down_ you'll also have to style the `:active` element via CSS.

Comment: using this i would have to incorporate js wouldn't I?  create a function myFunc(){} then add the func to the listner?

Comment: i also want it underlined on active element

Comment: @davidfromMLogicinc then use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`. I once again edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood, if not then I'm sorry :/

Create a :hover option for your html tag... for example I have "a" tag in HTML code like this:

```
<a href="somewhere.html">Take me somewhere</a>
```

and what I like to do is, that the color of this div will be red and when I point this div whit my mouse it will change the color to blue and make underline there, so my code in css will look like this:

```
a {
   color: #F00;
}

a:hover {
   color: #00F;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: He is wanting to do this dynamically via Javascript (so as to not affect the CSS file directly). Right concept, but different question.

Comment: he didn't include his code properly so it used to be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wasn't working because getElementsByTagName returns more then one element (it returns array object properties). You have to loop thought each one of it.
You can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g27bs/). I set *text-decoration* to *none* after click to be more clear.

In **test** function (which is called **onclick**) you iterate through every a tag that ElementsByTagName gave you. In this loop you set text-decoration property.

```
function test(){
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var l = 0; l < links.length; l++){
  links[l].style.textDecoration ='none';
}}
```

Comment: It's actually as simple as `onmousedown="this.style.textDecoration='underline'"`

Comment: I agree. But I just wanted to explain why posted code wasn't working.